# Return FileStream and text data in the same API result?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a API that return a FileStreamResult. It's working well, but I need to add more information in the return.

I'm using NetCore 2.2 in Back and Angular 8 in Front.

This is the signature of my API method:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("audio/{id}")]
public FileStreamResult GetAudioByINUM(string id)
```

I'm returning an audio Stream:

```
var resultStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(myWavPath);
```

Inside a FileStreamResult class, as below:

```
Response.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream").ToString();
streamResult = new FileStreamResult(resultStream, "application/octet-stream");
```

And I'm reading the response in Angular:

```
let dataType = "audio/wav"; //result.dataType;
let binaryData = [];
binaryData.push(data);
let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(binaryData, { type: dataType }));
this.audioURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

This code it's working well, but I need to add more informations in this response, as the autor of the audio, and his length, and other informations.

How could I change to return the audio stream, and also more informations (string's informations) at the same result? And How to read it from Angular? I've tried some things, but I'm receiving 406 Not Acceptable Response.

Comment: You could separate the stream data api and the info api into two different apis. That's what I do in my app.

Comment: Yeah, I thought this, but I've imagined that could have other way, simpler. Thanks!